# How to configure sendmail to only send to specified domains?

Tags: linux, centos, php, email, sendmail

I have a local development server (centos) which I develop a number of websites on. Occasionally I need to test email sending scripts.

I want to avoid the development server from sending emails to anyone who doesn't have an email address with a particular domain (ie: jon@mydomain.com, mary@mydomain.com, etc). So, I would like to create a white list or rule on the server which prevents emails being sent to any email address that doesn't match mydomain.com.

I'm currently using PHP's built-in mail() function. But I imagine this is something more on the server level and I would like something that will manage ANY emails sent out from the server from any program/app/script/etc.

**I can confirm that PHP is using /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail**

Answer (score 1):

here is how I managed to do it. In Sendmail, you need to modify the mailertable. Add the following:

```
alloweddomainname.com   alloweddomainname.com
.   error:
```

This will essentially send any emails to @alloweddomainname.com and error for anything else.

Comment: Have you considered using "catchall" local mailbox in default mailertable route? `.  local:catchall`

Answer (score 0):

PHP `mail()` function sends messages according to MTA set as `sendmail_path` value in `php.ini`, by default, it's set to following:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

on some systems it's a symlink to the binary of MTA, in my case it's sendmail-compatible binary of postfix MTA package, in other case it might be sendmail or qmail or whatever you use:

```
[root@giomacdesk ~]# ll /usr/sbin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 ივლ  3 11:33 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/mta
[root@giomacdesk ~]# ll /etc/alternatives/mta
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 ივლ  3 11:33 /etc/alternatives/mta -> /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
```

So, according to this you can:

A. change `sendmail_path` to your custom script, write parser and filter messages accordingly. This will affect only outgoing messages sent via PHP `mail()` where `sendmail_path` was changed.

B. change configuration of mail server - this will affect all messages sent via MTA of your server, to do this you must check what is your server and configure it accordingly

In case of postfix:

1. add following to the /etc/postfix/main.cf: `transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps`
2. create file `/etc/postfix/transport_maps` with following content:

   > ```
   >  alloweddomain.com :
   >  * discard:
   > ```
3. hash: run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport_maps`
4. restart postfix

Comment: I can confirm that it's /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail

Comment: I'd make life easier - install postfix, remove sendmail, enable postfix: `yum install postfix -y;yum remove sendmail;chkconfig postfix on;service postfix start`